# Передача значений в чужую консольную программу

Tags: c#, консоль

Имеется стороннее консольное приложение, в которое необходимо передавать значения. Передаю следующим образом:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SendKeys.SendWait( textBox15.Text + "{ENTER}");
        SendKeys.SendWait(textBox2.Text + "{ENTER}");
}
```

Само приложение запускаю так:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\****\****\****.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(myProcess.StartInfo.FileName);
myProcess.Start();
```

В таком случае значения передаются в любое активное окно. Как сделать чтобы они передавались именно в нужную программу.

---

В моем случае передавать значения, это просто отправлять в консоль вместо пользователя данные. Пример:

[image: Пример]

Программа просит ввести год я передаю значение 2016, потом значение 10 и т.д. Извините если выражаюсь не корректно.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "передавать значения"?

Comment: Любая программа имеет довольно незаметный для новичков потенциал - аргументы функции `main`. Попробуйте открыть нужную программу, заложив аргументы в `main`

Comment: @EgorRandomize - а если это чужая программа и она не обрабатывает аргументы командной строки?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ТС окутал всё завесой тайны: нам приходится только гадать, о чём идёт речь

Comment: @EgorRandomize ??? Он же написал, хоть и не туда, и не с того аккаунта.

Comment: @vindi пробовали [это](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput)?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - записать необходимые данные в файл, и вызвать cmd с перенаправлением ввода:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi=new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName="cmd";
psi.Arguments = "/k c:\\MyApp.exe < c:\\MyFile.txt";            
Process pr = new Process();
pr.StartInfo = psi;
pr.Start();
```

Более продвинутый способ, это `RedirectStandartInput`, однако при этом целевое приложение отвязывается от консольного окна, и его выходные данные придется выводить другим способом.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi=new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "c:\\MyApp.exe";
psi.Arguments = "";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process pr = new Process();
pr.StartInfo = psi;     
pr.Start();      

pr.StandardInput.WriteLine("Hello"); //передача данных в программу 

string s = pr.StandardOutput.ReadLine(); //получение вывода
MessageBox.Show("Program's output was: " + s);
```