# Перенаправление ввода в стороннюю программу

Tags: c#, консоль

Есть приложение, которое выполняет расчеты в зависимости от введенных координат (Широта, долгота). Программа изначально при открытии требует ввести вручную две координаты через Enter, после чего она создает отчет о расчетах в .txt и закрывается. Имеется много координат и вручную каждый раз открывать и вводить не вариант. Необходимо чтобы моя программа считывала все координаты и поочередно вводила координаты в чужую программу.

[image: пример работы программы]

Программу я открываю следующим образом:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"CalcVal.exe";
psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName);
process.Start();
```

Находил пример передачи значений из файла, для своего случая реализовывал так:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "cmd";
psi.Arguments = "/k c:\\CalcVal.exe < c:\\MyFile.txt";
psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName);
process.Start();
```

MyFile.txt содержит значения координат:

> 129.0705   71.63512
>
> 125.80822    76.7892

В данном случае программа не считывает не одного значения. Проблема именно в том что сторонняя программа не принимает вводимые значения от моей программы.

Как еще можно передать значения из файла?

Comment: Ну а как вы в программу передаете значения обычным образом? Через аргументы вызова?

Comment: @Bulson программа написана не мной, доступа к ее исходному коду нет, через какие аргументы вызова?

Comment: Пример: вызов программы из ком.строки `CalcVal.exe \Latitude 1234.122 \Longitude 456.123` - это передача через аргументы вызова данных для программы. Вы бы показали как в эту программу надо передавать данные, иначе не понятно как вам помочь.

Comment: Покажите полный код как вызываете с ключем /k

Comment: @Bulson очевидно, речь о передаче данных через стандартный ввод, а не аргументы командной строки

Comment: @Bulson вы правы, речь идет о передаче данных через стандартный ввод. Эмитировать ввод так как бы это сделал пользователь

Comment: Попробуйте убрать установку свойства psi.WorkingDirectory (она тут не нужна), и отделять каждое число в файле переводом строки (а не пробелом).

Comment: Используйте StandartInput https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18577/How-to-redirect-Standard-Input-Output-of-an-applic

Comment: Проблема в том, что в приведенном коде вы берете GetDirectoryName от строки "cmd", а не от реального имени файла (что, скорее всего, возвращает пустую строку или null)

Comment: Если не получиться через cmd, попробуйте второй способ из этого ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/787210/240512

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight про WorkDirectory мой косяк. Попробовал способ из ответа помогло, спасибо! как закрыть вопрос или пометить его решенным

Comment: Написать свой ответ и отметить его зеленой галкой.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача значений в чужую консольную программу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787110/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d1%83%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась данным способом:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "C:\\CalcVal.exe";
psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName);
psi.Arguments = "";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process pr = new Process();
pr.StartInfo = psi;
pr.Start();


pr.StandardInput.WriteLine("129.0705"); //передача данных в консоль
pr.StandardInput.WriteLine("71.63512"); //передача данных в консоль
```

Answer (score 2):

В качестве ответа я приведу более длинный, но зато более интересный вариант.

Допустим у нас есть некая консольная программа, а к ней хочется прикрутить графический интерфейс.

Для примера возьмем простую программу вычисляющую сумму двух чисел

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите 2 числа");
        Console.WriteLine();

        //получение чисел
        List<string> inputStrings = new List<string>();
        do
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) continue;

            inputStrings.Add(input);

        } while (inputStrings.Count() < 2);

        //вычисление суммы
        int result = 0;
        foreach (var input in inputStrings)
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(input, out int val))
            {
                result += val;
            }
        }

        //вывод результата
        Console.WriteLine($"Сумма чисел равна: {result}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Мы хотим данные для запуска такой нехитрой программы считывать из текстового файла и выводить в окно, допустим так

[image: пример работы]

Для работы с данными создадим такой класс

```
public class InputOutput : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }

    private int _Sum;
    public int Sum
    {
        get { return _Sum; }
        set
        {
            _Sum = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Sum)));
        }
    }
}
```

Создадим такой простенький интерфейс (проект WPF)

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBox x:Name="_textBoxProgram"
             Height="23"
             Canvas.Left="121"
             Canvas.Top="22"
             Width="285" />
    <Label Content="Путь к программе:"
           Canvas.Left="4"
           Canvas.Top="19" />
    <Button x:Name="_buttonSelectProgram"
            Content="Выбрать"
            Canvas.Left="418"
            Canvas.Top="25"
            Width="75"
            Click="_buttonSelectProgram_Click" />
    <TextBox x:Name="_textBoxFile"
             Height="23"
             Canvas.Left="121"
             Canvas.Top="63"
             Width="285" />
    <Label Content="Файл данных:"
           Canvas.Left="4"
           Canvas.Top="60" />
    <Button x:Name="_buttonSelectFile"
            Content="Выбрать"
            Canvas.Left="418"
            Canvas.Top="66"
            Width="75"
            Click="_buttonSelectFile_Click" />
    <Label Content="Данные"
           Canvas.Left="121"
           Canvas.Top="104" />
    <ListBox x:Name="_listBoxData"
             ItemsSource="{Binding DataAndResults}"
             Height="150"
             Canvas.Left="121"
             Canvas.Top="135"
             Width="120">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Value1}"></Run>
                    <Run Text=" + "></Run>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Value2}"></Run>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Label Content="Результат"
           Canvas.Left="279"
           Canvas.Top="104" />
    <ListBox x:Name="_listBoxResuls"
             ItemsSource="{Binding DataAndResults}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Sum"
             Height="150"
             Canvas.Left="279"
             Canvas.Top="135"
             Width="80" />
    <Button x:Name="_buttonResult"
            Content="Вычислить"
            Canvas.Left="418"
            Canvas.Top="262"
            Width="75"
            Click="_buttonResult_Click" />

</Canvas>
```

Как видно я воспользовался байдингом, но я не буду использовать MVVM, а сделаю все в кодбихайнд

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //коллекция данных и результатов
    private ObservableCollection<InputOutput> _DataAndResults;
    public ObservableCollection<InputOutput> DataAndResults
    {
        get { return _DataAndResults; }
        set
        {
            _DataAndResults = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DataAndResults)));
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;
    }


    //вызов диалога выбора файла и получение имени файла
    private string GetPathToFile(string exampleFile)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        System.IO.FileInfo example = new System.IO.FileInfo(exampleFile);

        openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
        openFileDialog.Filter = string.Format("{0} файлы ({1})|*{1}|Все файлы (*.*)|*.*",
                                example.Extension.Substring(1).ToUpper(),
                                example.Extension);

        bool? result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
        {
            return openFileDialog.FileName;
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }

    //указать путь к файлу ConsoleAppCalcVal
    private void _buttonSelectProgram_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._textBoxProgram.Text = GetPathToFile("app.exe");
    }

    //указать путь к файлу с данными, прочитать этот файл, отобразить данные
    private void _buttonSelectFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._textBoxFile.Text = GetPathToFile("text.txt");

        //читаем данные из файла
        ReadData(this._textBoxFile.Text);
    }

    //чтение входных данных, отображение данных
    private void ReadData(string file)
    {
        DataAndResults = new ObservableCollection<InputOutput>();

        try
        {
            foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(file))
            {
                string[] strs = line.Split( new char[] { ' ' },
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                InputOutput io = new InputOutput
                {
                    Value1 = Int32.Parse(strs[0]),
                    Value2 = Int32.Parse(strs[1])
                };

                DataAndResults.Add(io);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Не удалось прочитать файл", "Ошибка",
                MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }

    //старт вычисления
    private async void _buttonResult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataAndResults == null || DataAndResults.Count() == 0) return;

        this._buttonSelectProgram.IsEnabled = false;
        this._buttonSelectFile.IsEnabled = false;
        this._buttonResult.IsEnabled = false;

        try
        {
            foreach (var item in DataAndResults)
            {
                await ExecuteAndGetResult(item);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this._buttonSelectProgram.IsEnabled = true;
            this._buttonSelectFile.IsEnabled = true;
            this._buttonResult.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    //запуск консольной программы, получение результата
    private async Task ExecuteAndGetResult(InputOutput item)
    {
        //настройка процесса
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = this._textBoxProgram.Text,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        };

        //работа с процессом
        string output = String.Empty;
        using (Process p = Process.Start(psi))
        {
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(item.Value1);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(item.Value2);

            output = await p.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
            output = await p.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
            //третья строка выводит окончательный результат
            output = await p.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
        }

        //берем результат из полученной строки
        var ss = output.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (Int32.TryParse(ss.Last(), out int result))
        {
            item.Sum = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Текстовой файл данных такой

```
2 3
20 30
200 300
2000 3000
```